# Positional parameter cannot be found error in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to append the date to a file name in my Powershell script but keep getting the following error (my code is below the error).  Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
Set-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts 

argument '$null'.
At P:\CoverageVerifier\CombineTextFiles.ps1:8 char:50
+ ... thTrailer | Set-Content "${path}\\" + ${$dateStr} + "_CoverageVerifi ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

Here is my powershell code:

```
$path = "\\xx\\apps\\CoverageVerifier\\"
$pathHeader = "\\xx\\apps\\CoverageVerifier\\Header.txt"
$pathData = "\\xx\\apps\\CoverageVerifier\\Data.txt"
$pathTrailer = "\\xx\\apps\\CoverageVerifier\\Trailer.txt"
$date = Get-Date
$dateStr = $date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
#Write-Output $dateStr
Get-Content $pathHeader,$pathData,$pathTrailer | Set-Content "${path}\\cvgver." + ${dateStr} + ".0101"
```

Comment: Why are you doubling all backslashes? Are these UNC paths?

Comment: Yes they are UNC paths to a specific server on the network.  Sorry for my ignorance. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first positional parameter of the `Set-Content` cmdlet is the `-Path` parameter.
Because of the way you define the paths for the files, it is bound to have problems with that.

As I understand, these are UNC paths, so try this instead:

```
# for LOCAL paths
# Set the driveletter to the actual drive you are using. For demo I'm using 'X:\'
# $path        = 'X:\apps\CoverageVerifier'
# for UNC paths
# change 'servername' to your actual servers name
$path        = '\\servername\apps\CoverageVerifier'

$pathHeader  = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath 'Header.txt'
$pathData    = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath 'Data.txt'
$pathTrailer = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath 'Trailer.txt'
$dateStr     = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$outFile     = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ($dateStr + "_TestVerifier.txt")

Get-Content $pathHeader, $pathData, $pathTrailer | Set-Content $outFile
```

As you can see, I'm using the `Join-Path` cmdlet a lot to make sure my file paths get concatenated correctly.

Comment: Thanks Theo.  Appreciate your time and help.  I'll try it.

Comment: Thank you Theo.  That got it!!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the format operator and Join-Path?
**Edit** even with only one format

```
$path =        "\\xx\apps\CoverageVerifier"
$pathHeader =  Join-Path $path "Header.txt"
$pathData =    Join-Path $path "Data.txt"
$pathTrailer = Join-Path $path "Trailer.txt"

Get-Content $pathHeader,$pathData,$pathTrailer | 
  Set-Content (Join-Path $path ("{0:yyyyMMdd}_TestVerifier.txt" -f (Get-Date))
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help too.  This worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

you use set-content to modify the content of a file, not the filename:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6

Comment: Thanks Leon.  Do you know how to modify the file name?

Comment: Rename-Item:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-6